# Unpermitte no me guardan los parametros ruby on rails 5.1.1

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-3

hola es que no me estan guardando los parametros  cargo,gerencia y localidad y no se por que quien me ayude gracias 
[image: este es mi error]

Unpermitted parameters: :cargo, :gerencia, :localidad

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "cargo"
  t.string "gerencia"
  t.string "localidad"
  t.string "nombreemail"
  t.string "telefono"
  t.string "extension"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

**modelo**
 **user.rb**

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord  

      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :assignments
      has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] 

# GET /users/new
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :cargo, :gerencia, :localidad , :nombreemail,
  :telefono, :extension, :password,:email)
end
```

end

**new.html.erb**  registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>


   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel panel-default devise-bs">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><%= t('.sign_up', default: 'Registrarme') %></h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">

      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :nombre %>
        <%= f.text_field :name ,label: "Nombre completo",
  placeholder: "Ingrese el nombre completo",input_html: { title: 'Nombre del usuario' }, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'%> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Cargo %>
      <%= f.text_field :cargo ,
  placeholder: "Ingrese el nombre del cargo ",input_html: { title: 'Cargo del usuario' }, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'%>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Gerencia%>
      <%= f.text_field :gerencia  ,
  placeholder: "Ingrese el nombre de la gerencia ",input_html: { title: 'Gerencia del usuario' }, class: 'form-control'%>  
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :localidad %>
     <%= f.text_field :localidad ,
  placeholder: "Ingrese la planta donde elabora",input_html: { title: 'Localidad del usuario' }, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'%>  
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
   <center>
    <%= f.submit t('.sign_up', default: 'Sign up'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
   </center> 
<% end %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "select2-rails"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15'
gem 'mail'
```

Comment: Como recomendación, en futuras preguntas agrega el texto del error en vez de un pantallazo. El texto es indexable por los buscadores en caso que haya alguien con tu mismo problema, es mucho más fácil de leer para quienes contesten tu pregunta y mucho más fácil para ti, porque solo  seleccionas, copias y pegas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Devise* utiliza su propio controllador para crear los usuarios; si miras el *log*, podrás ver que el contolador es `Devise::RegistrationsController`, por lo que tu controlador `UsersController` no es necesario (por lo menos no para crear usuarios).

Para que *Devise* acepte los parámetros `cargo`, `gerencia` y `localidad`, debes configurarlos en el contolador `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:cargo, :gerencia, :localidad])
  end
end
```